# What is the meaning of "special option in your car?"

Tags: rock

The song *Don't Turn Your Back*, off of Blue Oyster Cult's album **Fire of Unknown Origin**, includes the line "You'll use that special option in your car." What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One interpretation I found online is the following:

"I believe this song to be about one of the segments of the sci-fi animated anthology film Heavy Metal (1981). Particularly the one with the taxi cab driver in the futuristic New York. now it's no secret that Vengeance was written for the film, but was not taken. Instead, Veteran of the psychic wars, a song that had already been written, was used. My guess is that Don't Turn Your Back was also written for the movie but not used.

The repeated line "don't turn your back" fit with the general mood, as the protagonists are on the run from power-hungry mobsters looking for a green orb from beyond the stars with unimaginable power.

"Don't turn your back, one chance to save her Don't turn your back, keep her out of danger, Don't turn your back, she'll return the favor She wants you so, don't say no" ----This is about the part where the cab driver, harry rescues a woman from being chased by thugs. And then that night they sleep together.

"Things are not always what they seem She won't always say what she means You'll never know who your friends really are You'll use that special option in your car" ---- **At the end of the segment, the two have escaped with the orb. harry is driving and the woman is in the backseat. She betrays him, pulling a gun on Harry. she'll kill him and take the power for herself. Harry sighs and flips a switch that's hidden on the floor of the cab with his foot. "You'll never know who your true friends really are. You'll use that special option in your car." The traitor is vaporized, only the suitcase remains in the backseat.**

I've tried to find confirmation for this online but I have not. I do know that the song was written at the right time for this theory to be plausible, and in my opinion, likely. I recommend watching the film. it's rather cheesy, and the ending doesn't really make sense, but its pretty cool. "

Source: https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/45656/

Comment: Wow! Thank you for that awesome answer!